# Banach algebra of functions under composition

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, banach-algebras

I have heard of constructing a Banach algebra of functions by defining the multiplicative operation as function composition. What is the formal name for this sort of construction? What work has been done on questions such as: if $\mathcal{B}$ is a compositional Banach algebra of functions and $f,g\in \mathcal{B}$, then do we have $\|g\circ f\| \leq \|g\|\|f\|$? When does equality hold? Apologies for the basic question.

Comment: The condition $\|g \circ f\| \leq \|g\|\, \|f\|$ holds by the definition of a Banach algebra

Comment: Note also that the multiplication needs to distribute over addition; that is: we need to have $f \circ (g + \alpha h) = f \circ g + \alpha f \circ h$.  This necessarily holds if our functions are linear maps.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom is there a name for this construction?

Comment: Sure, a "Banach algebra"

Comment: Sorry maybe I misinterpreted: which construction?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom a Banach algebra which specifically uses function composition as the multiplicative operation.

Comment: Well a common example is simply "bounded operators on a Hilbert space"